# How to sort an array of (x, y) cartesian coordinates so that the distance between one point and its adjacents its the mimimum?

Tags: sorting

Let's say we've got an array with the following elements:

```py
array = [(1, 0), (-1, 0), (0, 1), (0, -1)]
```

I want to order it so that between one element and its neighbors there's the minimum possible distance.
In this case, the output would be:

```py
array = [(1, 0), (0, -1), (0, 1), (-1, 0)]
```

What would be an algorithm to do that, considering the minuscule input size(n <= 10)?

At first I thought about a sort of bubble sort that compares three elements of the same time, but I'm not sure it could work.

Comment: Notably, this *is* the [Travelling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), which is the classing NP-hard problem - aka there. is no fast solution for large N.

Comment: But there are for small N, or for "approximate" answers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Computing_a_solution

Comment: What exactly do you mean with *"between one element and its neighbors there's the minimum possible distance"*? Why exactly should the example output be what you showed?

Comment: @MooingDuck Are you assuming that that means they want to minimize the ***sum*** of distances between neighbors? They didn't say that, did they?

Comment: KellyBundy: I thought it a safe assumption, but technically you're right. It could be that they want to minimize the square of the distances (similar to stat-sig calculations) or some other way of combining the individual distances.  EmKian - how did you want to combine the individual distances?

Comment: @MooingDuck Actually it can't be the sum. Or their example output is wrong. Since that has sum sqrt(2)+2+sqrt(2) instead of the also possible sqrt(2)+sqrt(2)+sqrt(2).

Comment: Good eye! I failed to notice that! I can't think of any valid interpretation to end with that result, so I suspect it's an error, but would definitely like confirmation from OP.

Comment: Yeah minimizing the sum of the distances between neighbors is what I wanted. My bad for the example output, I was typing it out of memory and didn't check it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Ok then please also fix that output (and clarify the task also in the question, not just in a comment). Hmm, for sum I had simple Python implementation with a few lines of code that tried all permutations and took about 10 seconds for 10 coordinates. But looks like I already deleted it when I realized that this apparently wasn't about sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a variant of the [Traveling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), finding the *minimum* route is hard and slow, even for relatively small N like 20.  However, there's a lot of heuristics you can use to get a *short* route.  I will explain two very simple algorithms that give reasonably short routes:

First, we use a greedy [Nearest Neighbor algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbour_algorithm) to pick a starting route:

- Pick a starting point, and put it at the front of your list.
- Iterate over each point not in the list, and calculate the distance-squared for each of them to the last item in the list. (`(y2-y1)^2 + (x2-x1)^2`) We skip `sqrt` because it is slow, and we don't actually need it here.
- add the point with the shortest distance to the end of the path.

  - While doing this, keep track of which pair had the longest distance-squared.
- At the end, calculate the distance from the last node to the first node, which turns this into a complete "tour".
- Whichever pair has the longest distance-squared, rotate the list so those nodes are the last and first nodes, so that the longest distance-squared in the loop is not part of your final path.

This algorithm is O(n^2), and gives you a reasonable path, usually about 25% longer than "the shortest" path.

Depending on your needs, you can stop here. If you want additional accuracy, then you can use a [Pairwise Exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Pairwise_exchange) (aka "2-opt") algorithm pass, which can shorten the path.

- For each node A

  - (The next node in the path from A, we'll call B.)
  - For each other edge C:

    - (The next node in the path from C, we'll call D.)
    - Calculate the distance (including sqrt) from A to C, and the distance (including sqrt) from B to D.
    - If (A-to-C plus B-to-D) is less than (A-to-B plus C-to-D),

      - then replace the old connections with these new ones
      - In a list, this can be done by reversing nodes between.
    - Example:

      - If we are analyzing the list (X Y Z **A B** E F G **C D** H I J)
      - And we find that (A-to-C plus B-to-D) is less than (A-to-B plus C-to-D)
      - Ten we reverse the nodes between `A` and `D`
      - Now our shortest path is (X Y Z A **C G F E B** D H I J).
- (Note that you should generally calculate as if there is a path from the last node to the first, but that all paths from any node *to* the start of the list always have length 0, since you don't actually care about that distance.)

This algorithm is O(N^2) each time you run it, but will usually shorten the path. More passes will shorten the path further, but also, obviously, takes more time. Note that the outermost for-loop only needs to iterate over paths that changed in the previous run, not all nodes. Repeating until no changes are made might take O(2^(N/2)) passes, so don't do that.

There are faster algorithms, but I like these two because they're very simple to understand, very simple to code, and produce very good results.